# Reveal menu that opens on click

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, menu, header

Hello I am currently working on a webpage located [here](http://dozzo.com.mx). It is a wordpress website and it uses a theme called The7, the theme includes a kind of menu called "Navigation on click" and it works perfectly, however I have been trying to set the initial state of the left menu as show-header instead of the default closed-header, and have not been able to do so.

I have noticed that inspecting the website initially the classes of the html, body and a div with id #page change from:

```
<html class= "js no-touch cssanimations csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions cssfilters mobile-false not-iOS">
<body class="home page page-id-11 page-template-default logged-in small-hover-icons header-side-left sticky-header slide-header-animation header-side-line header-above-side-line srcset-enabled btn-flat custom-btn-color custom-btn-hover-color filter-style-minimal contact-form-minimal small-fancy-datas semitransparent-bullets bold-icons phantom-fade phantom-shadow-decoration phantom-main-logo-on floating-mobile-menu-icon first-switch-logo-left first-switch-menu-right second-switch-logo-left second-switch-menu-right layzr-loading-on wpb-js-composer js-comp-ver-4.9.2 vc_responsive outlined-portfolio-icons album-minuatures-style-2 is-webkit no-mobile esg-blurlistenerexists closed-overlay-mobile-header">
<div id="page" class="closed-mobile-header">
```

to the following when manually opening the menu on the left.

```
<html class= "js no-touch cssanimations csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions cssfilters mobile-false not-iOS menu-open">
<body class="home page page-id-11 page-template-default logged-in small-hover-icons header-side-left sticky-header slide-header-animation header-side-line header-above-side-line srcset-enabled btn-flat custom-btn-color custom-btn-hover-color filter-style-minimal contact-form-minimal small-fancy-datas semitransparent-bullets bold-icons phantom-fade phantom-shadow-decoration phantom-main-logo-on floating-mobile-menu-icon first-switch-logo-left first-switch-menu-right second-switch-logo-left second-switch-menu-right layzr-loading-on wpb-js-composer js-comp-ver-4.9.2 vc_responsive outlined-portfolio-icons album-minuatures-style-2 is-webkit no-mobile esg-blurlistenerexists closed-overlay-mobile-header show-sticky-header">
<div id="page" class="closed-mobile-header show-header">
```

I have tried finding out if I can change the CSS or JS  values for the webpage but have not figured out where must I do so. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the theme and thus don't know for sure how it's structured. But, you should be able to do this by doing the following.

1. Adding **class** *open-menu* to <html>
2. Adding **class** *show-sticky-header* to <body>
3. Adding **class** *show-header* to <div id="page">

I would suggest the following approach.

1. Back up you website or at least the files involved.
2. Making sure you are working in a child theme.
3. Open up your themes files on at a time and look for where the tags are rendered by the theme.
4. Copy that file or files to your child theme
5. Modify it/them in the child theme to add the three classes.

If I had legitimate access to the theme I could definitely to you exactly where. Unfortunately it's $59. But, even if you are brand new to WP and PHP a slow thoughtful, methodical search like that would at least get you at least the exact place it needs to happen. If you still couldn't figure it out you could repost that section of your theme here and someone could help with the fine details.

I'm just not sure exactly how much help anyone could be without the theme in hand or at least the code in question.

Hope this helps,

Tim

P.S. Here's info on child themes in case you are unfamiliar.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes